# Return captcha image by Webservice (c#)

Tags: c#, web-services, captcha

I using [this article](http://www.stefanprodan.com/2012/01/user-friendly-captcha-for-asp-net-mvc/) for create captcha image and I put it's code in my WebService for return image'Captcha to client (app.js), But i have got many errors.

### My WebService:

```
public class Captcha : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public Bitmap CaptchaImage()
        {
            bool noisy = true;
            var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            //generate new question
            int a = rand.Next(10, 99);
            int b = rand.Next(0, 9);
            var captcha = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ?", a, b);

            //store answer
            Session["Captcha-1"] = a + b;

            //image stream
            FileContentResult img = null; //get error for FileContentResult

            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(130, 30))
            using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bmp))
            {
                gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

                //add noise
                if (noisy)
                {
                    int i, r, x, y;
                    var pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
                    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                        (rand.Next(0, 255)));

                        r = rand.Next(0, (130 / 3));
                        x = rand.Next(0, 130);
                        y = rand.Next(0, 30);

                        gfx.DrawEllipse(pen, x - r, y - r, r, r);
                    }
                }

                //add question
                gfx.DrawString(captcha, new Font("Tahoma", 15), Brushes.Gray, 2, 3);

                //render as Jpeg
                bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg"); //get error for .file
            }
                return img;
        }
}
```

Is there a way for solve these errors?!

Comment: In order to refer as "these errors", please provide error texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by this code in end:

```
   //render as Jpeg
   bmp.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   byte[] imageBytes = mem.ToArray();
   string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
   //img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg");
   return base64String;
}
//return img;
```